# Book: Scala in Depth, def foo[M[_]](f : M[Int]) = f, is _ really an existential type here?

Tags: scala, types, type-parameter

On page 136. page of the book "Scala in Depth" it is written:

[image]

But the following experiment suggests that here `_` is just the same as any arbitrary type parameter `T`, so it is perhaps not an existential type.

```
scala> def foo[M[_]](f : M[Int]) = f
foo: [M[_]](f: M[Int])M[Int]


scala> def foo[M[T]](f : M[Int]) = f
foo: [M[T]](f: M[Int])M[Int]
```

Also note the section 4.4 of the Scala Language Specification below , this also suggests that `_` is the same as `T` here.

Can someone explain what is going on here ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M[_]` in that context (i.e. as a type parameter declaration) is a higher kinded type (sometimes called a "type constructor"); as you say it's the same as `M[X]`, with the `_` just meaning we aren't going to reuse the name.

In a different context (e.g. as a type) the same syntax is sometimes used to mean an existential type `M[X] forSome { type X }`.

It's unfortunate and confusing that the syntax looks the same, but they're two different, unrelated features. If you're confused about which one a particular use of `_` is, maybe check what the compiler/language feature warning is? In my own code I try to always write existential types explicitly (using `forSome`) to avoid this confusion, but this is just something I came up with, not a rule that libraries tend to follow.